# use pure sql to generate result table

Tags: mysql, database, pivot-table

I have 2 table in mysql db.

[image]

and I want use sql to query out a table like this

[image]

how can I do this in  pure sql ?cause I don't want to use script to add and generate the result.

Comment: I cant see Your **Pure SQL** code you tried!

Comment: The jargon for what you seek is "pivoting." It's notoriously difficult, but not impossible, in MySQL.

Comment: @OllieJones I search that too,It's hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query-

```
SELECT etime,SUM(IF(epid=1,ecost,0)) AS A, 
SUM(IF(epid=2,ecost,0)) AS B, 
SUM(IF(epid=3,ecost,0)) AS C, SUM(ecost) AS Total 
FROM mytable GROUP BY etime;
```